# Why Anaconda installer doesn't recommend adding its directory to PATH on Windows?

Tags: windows, path, anaconda

[FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/) says it's because it *"can interfere with other software"*, but I couldn't find more details on that. The proposed workaround (opening Anaconda from Windows Start menu) is just too inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **base** environment includes a lot more than just the Conda binaries, specifically it has a Python installation and libraries. Leaving it on the PATH when activating other environments can lead to packages from the **base** env being loaded, i.e., violating the isolation that virtual environments are intended to have. Hence, in version 4.4, Conda introduced a mechanism (`conda activate`) to provide cleaner isolation and officially recommended against adding to PATH directly ([see Release Notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0)).  `conda activate` is a shell function that gets added to a shell via some lines being added to the initialization files (e.g., `.bashrc`).

Since Conda version 4.6, there has been a `conda init` command so that users can manage this initialization for multiple shells and not just have it added at installation time ([see Release Notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.6.0)). Windows users, for instance, can specifically use the `conda init powershell` in order to use Conda in a PowerShell prompt.